# IF ELSE Statement not working in a loop with Images and Genders

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, generator

I have a code taken from github. It should generate random faces from images, works fine. I now wanted to add a new gender to the code. At the moment it has "Male" and "Female" I wanted to add "Zombie" and "Alien".
Now I added the gender like the Male and Female are added in the code, this also works. The point where I can't find a solution is, that I added an else if condition to make the alien and zombie more rare than male and female, but this isn't working. The code only assigns a random gender face and there is no difference how often a gender appears.

I added the code below, I'm sorry that it's not reproducable. you can get the working code here:
[Master file, Github](https://github.com/usetech-llc/substrapunks/archive/refs/heads/master.zip)

```
 
 if (ranint > 500 <998) return "Female";
 else if (ranint < 2) return "Zombie";
 else if (ranint > 998) return "Alien";
 else return "Male";
}

async function saveFaceByCode(codeArr, outFile) {
  let images = [];
  for (let i=0; i < partTypes.length; i++) {
    if (codeArr[i] != 0) {
      const img = {
        src: `${partFolder}/${partTypes[i].name}${codeArr[i]}${ext}`,
        offsetX: partTypes[i].offset.x,
        offsetY: partTypes[i].offset.y,
      }
      images.push(img);
    }
  }

  // Generate image
  await mergeImagesToPng(images, outFile);
}


async function generateFaces() {

  // Array that lists all characters
  let characters = [];

  // Save attributes and generate map of attributes to saved array index
  let attrArray = [];
  let attrMap = {};
  let attrFreq = {};
  let attrCount = 0;
  for (let i=0; i < partTypes.length; i++) {
    for (let j=1; j<=partTypes[i].count; j++) {
      if (partTypes[i].attrNames[j-1].length > 0) {
        attrArray.push(partTypes[i].attrNames[j-1]);
        attrMap[partTypes[i].attrNames[j-1]] = attrCount;
        attrFreq[partTypes[i].attrNames[j-1]] = 0;
        attrCount++;
      }
    }
  }
  let attrjs = `const attributes = ${JSON.stringify(attrArray)};`;
  attrjs += "\n\nmodule.exports.attributes = attributes;";
  fs.writeFileSync(outputAttributesJS, attrjs);

  // "Code array" contains the code of current "face"
  // Initialize it to the first "face"
  let codeArr = [];
  for (let i=0; i < partTypes.length; i++) {
    if (partTypes[i].required) 
      codeArr.push(1);
    else
      codeArr.push(0);
  }
  let imgCount = 0;

  // In the loop generate faces and increase the code by one
  let exhausted = false;
  while (!exhausted) {
    // Check if combination is valid
    let gender = detectGender(codeArr);
    let valid = checkAttributeCompatibility(codeArr);

    // Skip faces randomly to get close to desired count
    const r = (getRandomInt(1000)+1)/1200;
    // const r = 0;
    if ((r <= desiredCount/totalFaces) && (gender != "Invalid") && (valid)) {
      // Generate and save current face
      await saveFaceByCode(codeArr, `${outputFolder}/image${imgCount}${ext}`);

      // Add character with accessories
      c = {
        id: imgCount,
        gender: gender,
        attributes: []
      };
      for (let i=0; i < partTypes.length; i++) {
        if (partTypes[i].attrNames.length != 0)
          if (codeArr[i] != 0) {
            let attrName = partTypes[i].attrNames[codeArr[i]-1];
            if (attrName.length > 0) {
              c.attributes.push(attrMap[attrName]);
              attrFreq[attrName]++;
            }
          }
      }
      characters.push(c);

      imgCount++;
    } else {
      // console.log(`Skipping. r = ${r}, gender = ${gender}, codeArr=${codeArr}`);
    }

    // Increate code by 1
    let canIncrease = false;
    for (let i=0; i < partTypes.length; i++) {
      if (codeArr[i] < partTypes[i].count) {
        canIncrease = true;
        codeArr[i]++;
        for (let j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
          if (partTypes[j].required)
            codeArr[j] = 1;
          else
            codeArr[j] = 0;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!canIncrease) exhausted = true;
    if (imgCount == desiredCount) break;
  }

  // Save characters' JSON
  fs.writeFileSync(outputCharacterJSON, JSON.stringify(characters));

  console.log("Total generated characters: ", imgCount);
  console.log("Attribute frequencies: ", attrFreq);
}

async function generateManually() {

  // Женин любимый
  code = [1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1];
  await saveFaceByCode(code, "test.png");

  let punks = require("./generated_faces/characters.json");
  c = {
    id: 10000,
    gender: "Male",
    attributes: [3,7,13,21,29]
  };
  punks.push(c);
  fs.writeFileSync("characters.json", JSON.stringify(punks));
}

async function main() {
  await generateFaces();
  // await generateManually();
}

main();

// function test() {
//   code = [1, 6, 2, 4, 4, 1, 8, 1];
//   console.log(detectGender(code));
// }
// test();
```

The part I edited is:

```
function detectGender(codeArr) {
  let male = false;
  let female = false;
  let zombie = false;
  let alien = false;
  for (let i=0; i < partTypes.length; i++) {
    if (codeArr[i] != 0) {
      const attrGender = partTypes[i].attrSex[codeArr[i]-1];
      if (attrGender == "m") male = true;
      if (attrGender == "f") female = true;
      if (attrGender == "z") zombie = true;
      if (attrGender == "a") alien = true;
    }
  }

  if (male && female) return "Invalid";
  if (male && zombie) return "Invalid";
   if (male && alien) return "Invalid";
    if (female && alien) return "Invalid";
      if (female && zombie) return "Invalid";
       if (alien && zombie) return "Invalid";
  if (male) return "Male";
  if (female) return "Female";
  if (zombie) return "Zombie";
  if (alien) return "Alien";
    
var ranint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
 
 if (ranint > 500 <998) return "Female";
 else if (ranint < 2) return "Zombie";
 else if (ranint > 998) return "Alien";
 else return "Male";
}
```

I know that this is not coded well... I'm just a beginner trying to modify something  found online.

Comment: This is wrong: `if (ranint > 500 <998)`. What did you mean to do here?

Comment: here I want to return "Female" when ranint is bigger 500 and smaller 998

Comment: @Max - That isn't what that code does, it does `ranint > 500`, then `(true/false) < 998`. You want `if (ranint > 500 && ranint < 998)`.

Comment: I'm sure we have a canonical dupetarget for this but I'm not having any luck finding it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thank you! changed it! and I will check online what canonical dupetarget means and maybe I can find it!

Comment: @Max canonical duplicate target means a question/answers on Stack Overflow that acts as a general answer for this kind of confusion. Usually, a question will be closed and marked as duplicate of the "canoncial" question (it's not a bad thing by itself) if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the following block will in all likelihood return a String of sorts - first one that evaluates True:

```
  if (male && female) return "Invalid";
  if (male && zombie) return "Invalid";
   if (male && alien) return "Invalid";
    if (female && alien) return "Invalid";
      if (female && zombie) return "Invalid";
       if (alien && zombie) return "Invalid";
  if (male) return "Male";
  if (female) return "Female";
  if (zombie) return "Zombie";
  if (alien) return "Alien";
```

so the random code after that will never run.

Also, as mentioned the following should read (I presume)

```
if (ranint > 500 && ranint < 998) return "Female";
```

Comment: does that mean I should delete this part?

Comment: Its really up to you to determine which code you want - and which you don't.  The function apparently returns a String - and you seem to have 2 different approaches of determining this String within one method.

Comment: I deleted the return part but I still get nearly the same ammount of each gender. thats crazy :D

Answer (score 1):

I would say the problem lies in the last lines, those *else if* are invalid syntax. I'd write your function like this:

```
if (ranint > 500 && ranint < 998) {
   return "Female"
} else if (ranint < 2) {
   return "Zombie"
} else if (ranint > 998) {
   return "Alien"
} else {
   return "Male"
}
```

If you open the console in your browser (hitting F12 most likely) and write this function:

```
function getType() {
    let ranint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
    if (ranint > 500 && ranint < 998) {
       return "Female"
    } else if (ranint < 2) {
       return "Zombie"
    } else if (ranint > 998) {
       return "Alien"
    } else {
       return "Male"
    }
}
```

And execute it by calling *getType()* you'll get *Female* most of the time, at least that is my experience.

And as mentioned in @batman567 answer, there are elements within your function that are making this code unreachable, namely:

```
if (male && female) return "Invalid";
if (male && zombie) return "Invalid";
if (male && alien) return "Invalid";
if (female && alien) return "Invalid";
if (female && zombie) return "Invalid";
if (alien && zombie) return "Invalid";
if (male) return "Male";
if (female) return "Female";
if (zombie) return "Zombie";
if (alien) return "Alien";
```

If any of these conditions evaluates to *True*, the function will return at that point (it will return wathever value is written after the *return*) and the rest of the function **won't have any effect on the result at all.**

Comment: thank you for the answer! I changed this but I still don't get the right output. I get nearly the same ammount of female, male, zombie and alien images. I think there should me less alien and zombies than male and female.

Comment: I would suggest you isolate this part of the code and run it (automatically) a thousand times at least to verify that it works as it should.